# Recursively finding all combinations 'n' of set<int> stored in a map. How do I "choose"?

Tags: c++, recursion, combinations

I understand the overarching idea of what I want to do, but I'm not sure how to begin with implementation. I have a map of named int sets. Meaning the keys are strings and the values are set.

```
map<string, set<int> > data;
```

I want to find the max # of unique ints shared between 'n' sets. So I need to check all possible combinations and update some max variable every time I come across a better combination.

From what I gather I need to use Iterators to traverse through the map values. So am I carrying around 'n' Iterators in my recursive function? What would my base case even look like? Would it be it.end() of the first value being chosen? I'm a bit lost as you can imagine.

I am willing to abandon the map (tho I'd prefer to stick with it so that I can keep a name) and use something simpler like a vector for the sets if that simplifies things (which it seems like it might). Hmm...

Comment: Just a thought: You could try constructing the universe of all `int`s that exist in any set in the map, while keeping a count of how many sets each `int` appears in.  
Then immediately throw away all the `int`s that were found in less than `n` sets. Now you only need to consider the sets which contain atleast one of the `int`s that remained. It seems like you still would need to check combinations of these surviving sets.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to find the number N such that N is in more of the `set`s than any other number?